# Simple Audio Player in Xamarin forms project doesn't work

Tags: forms, xamarin

I've just installed a package from nuget package manager Simple Audio Player and I wanted to play a sound or audio file but it doesn't work. In preferences of this project I accepted permission for r audio record and sti;; the same problem the code:

```
         public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ISimpleAudioPlayer simpleAudioPlayer =                   CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.CreateSimpleAudioPlayer();;
            Stream beepStream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("App1.Beep.mp3");
            ARandomMethod();
        }
```

```
    private void ARandomMethod()
    {
        
          if(sth happens)
          {
               simpleAudioPlayer.Play(); 
          }

    }
```

The error:
1)

```
        Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
         Error  NU1202  Package 
     Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.WPF 1.6.0 is not compatible with monoandroid13.0 (MonoAndroid,Version=v13.0). Package 
    Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.WPF 1.6.0 supports: net45 
    (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)    NewTimer.Android     
        C:\Users\PC\source\repos\NewTimer\NewTimer
      \NewTimer.Android\NewTimer.Android.csproj 1

    2)

          Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
              Error CS0103  The name 'simpleAudioPlayer' does not exist in the current context  NewTimer    C:\Users\PC\source\repos\NewTimer\NewTimer\NewTimer\MainPage.xaml.cs    86  Active
```

How do I solve this problem to play sound or music using Simple Audio player?

Answer (score 1):

this is a basic C# error.  You are declaring a local variable inside a method, then trying to use it in another method.  If you want to reference an object from multiple methods, you have to declare it at the **class level** so it remains in scope.

```
    // declare this at the class level so it remains in scope
    ISimpleAudioPlayer simpleAudioPlayer

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        simpleAudioPlayer = CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.CreateSimpleAudioPlayer();;
```

Comment: But the first error still occurs

Comment: Should I be worried or ignore it?

Comment: is it an **identical error**, or the same error message on a different line of code?  Are you perhaps making the same mistake with a different line of code?

Comment: Noo it's about version of netframework

Comment: is not compatible with monoandroid13.0 (MonoAndroid,Version=v13.0). Package 
    Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.WPF 1.6.0 supports: net45 
    (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)

Comment: Sorry, didn’t see that.  You are using a WPF nuget package in an Android project, so of course it won’t work.  Use the correct nuget for your platform

Comment: Which one is best for Andoid xamarin

Comment: The one without `.WPF` at the end: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer/. WPF stands for "Windows Presentation Foundation".